# Modifying download behaviour of drush

Tags: drush

By default the command:

```
drush dl <drupal-version>
```

will download the specified version of drupal from the internet. Is it possible to reconfigure drush so that dl looks to a local repo for the require drupal version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  the `--source` flag to provide your own xml release history file containing paths to your own gzips. (`drush dl drupal` defaults to http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x.)

Sadly I don't think you can specify a local repo, or even a remote repo as the source of a project for dl. Drush expects a gzip file to download and unpack. You could however write your own drush command that takes a local repo path, gzips it, and passes the gzip to dl.